Javascript keyup event when return pressed twice after text entered, the output displays extra carriage return in output
I have this code:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      $("#placeholder").on("click", function(){
           $("#contentHtml").focus();
           $(this).hide();
      })        
                            
      $("#contentHtml").on("keyup", function(e){
           var contentValue = e.target.innerText;
           window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(contentValue);
           if($(this).html().length === 0){
                $("#placeholder").show();
           } else {
                $("#placeholder").hide();
           }
      });
});

So if I typed:
this is line 1 <- then pressed enter and typed "this is line 2"

I would get:
this is line 1
this is line 2

but if I hit enter twice after "this is line 2" and typed "this is line 3"
I would get:
this is line 1
this is line 2


this is line 3

but I hit enter twice after "this is line 2", so I should get:
this is line 1
this is line 2

this is line 3

I understand why this is happening, how would I remove that extra enter space when hitting the return key twice?

Use .value to get what has been typed into a textarea, not .innerText.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Any reason why you're switching between vanilla JS and jQuery in the function? Why not $(this).text() instead of e.target.innerText?

if i use $(this).text() and i type "this is line 1" and hit enter  and type "this is line 2" the the output would be "this is line 1this is line 2" so the $(this).text() concatenates the values type and does not cater for the carriage returns.

@Barmar, the data is coming back from webview in react native so im using window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(contentValue); and doing the maniuplation on the react side

I just checked the jQuery source code. The .text() method just uses .textContent.

@Barmar I cant use .value because the text is coming back from a div with contentediable=true
